# Calculated in what direction should i go

Tags: javascript

I have a function with 2 parameters `FROM` and `TO`. `TO` can only be `0`, `90`, `180` or `270`. `FROM` can be some number between `0` and `360`.

- If `FROM` and `TO` are same function should return that number.
- If `FROM` is for example `181` and TO is `0` return `181+1`
- but if `FROM` `179` return `179-1`

Given 360°, calculate which direction is shortest to get from `FROM` to `TO`.

How to write this function without hundred lines of if and else.

```
nearestPath: function(from ,to){
        to = to%360;
        from = from%360;
        if(from == to){
            return to;
        }else{
            // Calculate increment or decrement..
        }

    }
```

Comment: So where is your function?

Comment: I think you're going to have to explain that logic **a lot** better ?

Comment: Convert that English into code.

Comment: Is `181++` a string?

Comment: You are going to have to explain the logic for why `TO === 0, FROM === 181` should return `181++` and why `TO === 0, FROM === 179` should return `179--`

Comment: @MladenStanojevic: No, it isn't. Did you mean it should do `FROM++` and `FROM--`?

Comment: @Mladen Stanojevic `181++` is a number? Are you sure? Or you mean `182 (181+1)`?

Comment: yes. FROM needs to go in shorter direction to TO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```js
function calc(from, to) {
    from = from%360;
    to = to%360;
    if (from === to) {
        return from;
    }
    var d = from - to - 180;
    if (d > 0 || d < -180) {
        return ++from;
    }
    return --from;
}

var to = +prompt("TO");
var from = +prompt("FROM");

alert(calc(from,to));
```